# How to eliminate duplicate constants in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have code using two constants, each describing the size of an array in different ways:

```
const  ArraySize = 1024;
       ArrayBits = 10;    //2^10 = 1024 bits
```

How do I express one of these in terms of the other?  The compiler will not allow use of Log2 or LdExp in constants.

Answers for any version of Delphi are OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const
  ArrayBits = 10;
  ArraySize = 1 shl ArrayBits;
```

The value of a shl b is equal to a * 2^b, so 1 shl ArrayBits is equal to 2^ArrayBits.

Comment: Wouldn't you know - when I looked at it today I saw the answer staring me in the face in the code.  Jumped over here, and found you guys had answered in minutes.  Great job.

Answer (score 9):

Well, you could do this:

```
const  
  ArrayBits = 10;
  ArraySize = 1 shl ArrayBits;
```

But I probably would shy away from that. It feels a little too obscure for me. In my opinion you should use arithmetic operators when you are performing arithmetic.

I'd probably leave your code as it is and add an assertion in the runtime code that the two constants were appropriately related. Document it with a comment as well.

Comment: "In my opinion you should use arithmetic operators when you are performing arithmetic." -- Sure, that seems fair in principle, but when there is no arithmetic operator that does what you want, I see no problem with using a bitwise operator.

Comment: @hvd That's fine. It's just my own personal opinion and preference.

Comment: I wanted it for what I feel is a very good reason.  Even though the lines are adjacent, I made the mistake of changing one and not the other.  I was focused on the code, decided to change the Array Size, Ctrl-clicked to the declaration, changed it, and popped back.  Then wasted 15 min. wondering what was wrong.  If I (the author) can do that, how can I leave it that way?  (What can I say?  I was tired last night, and tired is stupid.)  The rule is: if two parts are dependent, make the dependency blatant.  Oh, and the comment on the second line was intended to indicate dependency, and failed.

Comment: I fully understand your motivation. I just don't like doing arithmetic with bit shifts. For some arithmetic no amount of bit shifting can suffice. That's why I suggested an assertion which would have prevented your error.

Comment: Welllll, an Assert would *catch* the error, not prevent it. </pedantic> :-)  But an Assert would be in the code, away from the declarations in the Interface.  And the one thing I did not want to do was move this into the Implementation.  I have three constants: ArrayBits=10; ArraySize=1 shl Bits; and ArrayMask=ArraySize-1;  The code reads clearly as Index := Hash and ArrayMask; where it would be obscure to write Index := Hash and ((1 shl ArrayBits)-1);

Comment: It's up to you how you do it.